# How to use a non-polymorphic lambda in Boost Proto/Phoenix?

Tags: c++, boost, c++11, boost-phoenix, boost-proto

I'd like to provide an API which accepts a user-defined Boost Phoenix lambda. Unlike a C++11 lambda, a Phoenix lambda is polymorphic.

I am able to use the `[]` operator of a lambda argument. The following snippet will output the first element of array `arr`:

```
int arr[4] = {1,2,3,4};
cout << _1[_2](arr,0) << endl;
```

How can I allow the user to access member data or methods of a lambda argument? The following code snippet, for example, fails to compile; giving: **error: ‘const type’ has no member named ‘x’**

```
struct vec2 { float x,y; };
vec2 v2{1,2};
cout << ((_1).x)(v2) << endl;
```

Comment: Try `((&_1)->*&vec2::x)(v2)`.

Comment: Thanks, that's very helpful. I must admit though, thinking of the end user, I was hoping for something easier on the eye.

Comment: Is there no way even `static_cast_` might help? Alas it gives a similar error with `static_cast_<vec2>(_1).x`.

Comment: It cannot help, no. You can write an `x` such that `x(_1)` means 'a functor which fetches the `x` member of its first parameter'. See documentation on how to write functors.

Comment: Thanks again. It's good to look at that solution, but it only makes me run back to your first. I certainly wouldn't choose to ask the user to create a function object for each member access.

Comment: You can also use `phx::bind(&vec2::x,_1)(v2)` that is IMHO slightly less ugly (but only slightly). If you want a general solution where you can use arbitrary structs I believe you are out of luck. If you want only several specific structs, you could consider doing something similar to [this](http://www.boost.org/libs/phoenix/example/container_actor.cpp)(explained [here](http://www.boost.org/libs/phoenix/doc/html/phoenix/examples/extending_actors.html)).

Comment: Thanks for the links @llonesmiz; and yes, it is just slightly less ugly :)

Comment: I've noticed that the example I linked above doesn't compile (at least not on 1.53.0). Changing `phoenix::expression::function` to `phoenix::detail::expression::function_eval` in the return types of the member functions apparently makes it work.